# R: Creating a dataframe from an irregular vector

Tags: r

I’m looking to take an irregular vector of information scraped from a webpage, and turn it into a dataframe.

For example, given a vector that looks like this:

```
vec <- c("Bank of America", "6%", "JP Morgan", "5%", "Bank of China", "UBS", "7%")
```

I would like to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- tibble(bank.name = c("Bank of America", "JP Morgan","Bank of China","UBS"), interest.rate = c(6%, 5%, NA, 7%))
```

The bank name column is easy to create using regex. But, I'm struggling to create a vector for interest rates that puts the NA in the right spot.

Edits after reading answer from @guscht:

@guscht had a great vectorized answer for this question! I was worried we'd have to use a for loop...

Also, I translated the solution from @guscht into the grammar of the tidyverse, and it looks like this:

```
test <- c("Bank of America", "6%", "JP Morgan", "5%", "Bank of China", "UBS", "7%")
df <- tibble(bank = test, rate = lead(test,1))

df %>%
    filter(str_detect(bank, "%")== FALSE) %>% #Includes only rows that are banks
    mutate(rate = ifelse(str_detect(rate, "%") == TRUE, rate, NA)) # converts non-rate values to NA
```

Comment: Could you indicate which package the function "tibble" is from?

Comment: @guscht It's from `tidyverse` or `tibble`

Comment: @guscht Tibbles are an object from Hadley Wickham's Tidyverse, you can read Wickham's explanation for it here: [R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/introduction-2.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
library(data.table) # using data.table because the syntax is nicer
test <- c("Bank of America", "6%", "JP Morgan", "5%", "Bank of China", "UBS", "7%")
dt <- data.table(bank.name = test, interest.rate = shift(test, n = 1, type = "lead"))
dt <- dt[! grepl("%", bank.name)]
dt[! grepl("%", interest.rate), interest.rate := NA]
dt
#           bank.name interest.rate
# 1:  Bank of America            6%
# 2:        JP Morgan            5%
# 3:    Bank of China            NA
# 4:              UBS            7%
```